# How do you update a database from external source

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I have multiple data sources that that are used to update the same Postgres database on a daily basis. Each row needs to be inserted or updated based on an `external_id` field, and the status needs to be updated.

How do you manage the delta between yesterday's data and today's? Typically, if a record is in the external data file, its status should be `active`, but if it's not longer present on a subsequent import, the record in my local database should be set to `hidden`.

For example, yesterday's file would include the external_ids `1,2,3,4,5` and today's file has `1,3,4,5,6,7`. After today's update, only records `1,3,4,5,6,7` should have an `active` status, and `2` should be set to `hidden`.

I suppose you could do `UPDATE items SET status = 'hidden' WHERE id NOT IN (1,3,4,5,6,7)`. However, I need to update everything that's not in a set of tens of thousands of external_ids.

What's the more efficient way to approach this?

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'd:

- `CREATE UNLOGGED TABLE` for the new data then `COPY` it in; or
- Create a foreign data wrapper that exposed the external data as if it was a table

then

- Do a big full outer join between the local and external data as part of an `UPDATE` that sets flags and updates values in a single large set operation. You might batch this into smaller chunks and/or parallelize it if needed.

If a FDW or bulk import of the external data is not feasible, then you'd usually do it using external workqueue systems.